# How do You Call Header.html/Footer.html in a Web Page?

Tags: php, html, include

I've been making a website with about 25 pages and every time I want to update the nav bar, or the footer, I have to go through every page and make the change!

Surely there is a way to have the header and the footer (and the side bar!) in separate documents and call them in the same way a CSS is called so they don't have to be repeated on every page.

Bonus: Is this likely to affect SEO in any way? Might it slow down the site?

Thank you,

Tara

Comment: -1 for asking a question that can be answered in 10 minutes on google; (I'm in a harsh mood tonight, sorry).

Comment: @vascowhite Actually, I've spent all morning looking on Google and I can't find an answer! Lots of people are saying very different things.

Comment: because there are so many different technics, you have to choose one and read more about it to learn :)

Comment: @vascowhite do you mean http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140051(v=office.10).aspx ? :))

Comment: @Tara Honestly, this is a question I answered for myself years ago purely through online tutorials that I found through Google. I can't believe they've all jus disapeared! Just putting your title into google brings up several useful [resources](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=How+do+You+Call+Header.html%2FFooter.html+in+a+Web+Page%3F&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=ab701688ab0f1ee8&biw=1680&bih=897). Ignore the first one it's your question :)

Comment: @gaRex if it works for you... :)

Comment: @vascowhite To expand on what I've said already: there *are* pages on Google about this topic, but I found them all too conflicting and complicated. @Lawrence made it simple and provided an example of how to implement it. So maybe the info was out there, but the format it was in just wasn't practical or digestible for me (and I suspect many others). Thanks for your input in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using include():

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Your page</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--Your styles ect that make your page-->
</style></head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><?php include('./site_content/header.html');?></div>
  <div class="sidebar"><?php include('./site_content/sidebar.html');?></div>
  <div class="content">
  your content
  </div>
  <div class="footer"><?php include('./site_content/footer.html');?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: np, experiment with php variables and you can turn your 25 static html pages into 1 page that calls other pages/content based on what links are clicked ect...

Comment: That sounds a bit like AJAX? From an SEO standpoint, I think that separate 'niche' pages will probably work better. But it's a cool idea in any case. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML itself - ignoring framesets and iframes which do have an effect on SEO and are generally not really recommended - does not have any method to include partial HTML.

You can however use PHP (or SSI if you're oldskool) for such. It has a command to include partial files, it's called [`include` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

PHP needs to be activated on your server for it. To keep this transparent you might want to map the `.html` file extension to PHP or use Mod_Rewrite to do that. That depends on the type of server and it's configuration.

> Might it slow down the site?

The server has more work to do to process the request, therefore it slows down the site a little bit. But normally for a simple site you won't notice that much.

To prevent such, it's possible to build a simple caching mechanism on top that will convert the dynamic PHP output into static files on the fly.